# Sails JS save after collection add...model missing newly added record

Tags: sails.js

I must be misunderstanding this bullet point from the save documentation:

- If you have any associations on the model they will currently be populated when you call .save(). This could cause issues with memory so to prevent this, you can take advantage of an experimental feature: passing in an options argument with populate: false set. Example: .save({ populate: false }, function() {})

http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/records/save

My code...

```
 //Person.js
    attributes: {
    name: {
        type: 'string'
    },

    pets: {
        collection: 'pet',
        via: 'owner'
    },

  }

//Pet.js
attributes: {
    animal: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    owner: {
        model: 'person'
    }
  }

//PersonController.js
create: function(req, res) {
        Person.create({
            name: 'Bob'
        }).populate('pets').exec(function(err, person) {
            person.pets.add({animal: 'dog'})
            person.save(function(err) {
                console.log(person);
            });


        })
    }
```

And my output is Bob with no pets.

Comment: and how about record in database? is it updated?

Comment: Yes. In my actual app I want to reference the collection for socket messages. Right now I just query the same record again but that seems wrong.

Comment: Which version of Sails are you using? v0.11 or v0.12?

Comment: Sorry I should have specified. 0.12.11

Comment: In v0.11 `save` callback used to have a second argument, the updated model. `{ populate: false }` seem like an option for that. This second argument is removed in v0.12.